# Telegram API methods - 404 error | java

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

Created a bot and group. Added bot to the group(as admin) and starting trying posts. Through Url, it's smooth and successful. Started off exploring Telegram API(JAVA). Tests were on `getUpdate` and `sendMessage` methods.

I have generated TOKEN from telegram webapp(https://web.telegram.org).

Code snippet to getUpdates: yes, I have included `bot` ahead of the token.

```
        TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot("BOT_TOKEN");

        GetUpdates getUpdates = new GetUpdates().limit(100).offset(0).timeout(0);
        GetUpdatesResponse gur = bot.execute(getUpdates);
        List<Update> list = gur.updates();

        for(Update update : list) {
            System.out.println(update.message());
        }
```

Resonse is null.

code for sendMessage:

```
        SendMessage request = new SendMessage(chatId, text)
                .parseMode(ParseMode.HTML)
                .disableWebPagePreview(true)
                .disableNotification(true)
                .replyToMessageId(1)
                .replyMarkup(new ForceReply());

        // sync
        SendResponse sendResponse = bot.execute(request);
        boolean ok = sendResponse.isOk();
        Message message = sendResponse.message();
        System.out.println(ok);
        System.out.println(message);
```

Response is false and null.

I'm referring `https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api#send-message`

Help me understand the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: What is your token format?

Comment: @Sean how do I describe the format? Like this: bot12345:ABCD_xyz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `109780439:AAJqs_w-4` format token, for instance:

```
TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot("109780439:AAJqs_w-4");
```

This token can be obtained from [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather).

Comment: This is what @BotFather created(truncated middle part of token for security) for my bot: 547789316:AAF36_jqfk

Comment: I mean, no `bot` prefix

Comment: Yes, it worked. Also by disabling replyToMessageId(1). Please update your answer in detail to not use bot as a prefix so that someone could make use of. Thanks